# Python comparing three arrays and return the True if the value is the largest among the three

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Let's say I have three arrays

```
a = np.array([1,3,5])
b = np.array([2,4,3])
c = np.array([3,2,1])
```

and I want to count how many times each variable is the largest one.
Here is the result I want:

```
a = [False, False, True] #since the last element of a, 5 is the largest among the three arrays
b = [False, True, False] #since the second element of b, 4 is the largest among the three arrays
c = [True, False, false] #since the first element of c, 3 is the largest among the three arrays
```

so that I can use sum() to count the number of each variable being the largest one.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally the following code should work:

```py
a, b, c = [x==np.max(x) for x in (a, b, c)]
```